# Future builder with switch flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a switch. by default switch value is true. when switch value change i need to re-run my future and get new data. but now it's not re-run.

this is my method

```
  Future<List<RequirementModel>> getRequirement(bool check)async{
    if(check){
      await CacheData().getUID().then((uid) {
        db.getServiceSubCategories(uid).listen((serviceSub) {
          db.getRequirements().listen((requirement) {
            ...
                  setState(() {
                    model.add(requirement[i]);
                  });
            ...
          });
        });
      });
    }else{
      await CacheData().getUID().then((uid) {
        db.getRequirements().listen((requirement) {
          ...
            setState(() {
              model.add(requirement[i]);
            });
          ...
        });
      });
    }
    return model;
  }
```

I added future inside didChangeDependencies
      Future> _future;

```
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    if(check){
      _future = getRequirement(check);
    }else{
      _future = getRequirement(check);
    }
  }
```

FutureBuilder Widget

```
FutureBuilder<List<RequirementModel>>(
                future: _future,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                 if(snapshot.hasData){
                   return ListView.builder(...
                         );
                       });
                 }else{
                   return Center(
                     child: RefreshProgressIndicator(
                       backgroundColor: Palette.white,
                     ),
                   );
                 }
                }
              )
```

Switch widget

```
         Switch(
            value: check,
            onChanged: (v) {
              setState(() {
                check = v;
              });
            }),
```

when i added like this: it's re-running without stoping. duplicate issue..

```
 FutureBuilder<List<RequirementModel>>(
                future: getRequirement(check),
```

**Solution**

I added my own solution below answer section. Please check and let me know, Is it best practice way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implements two FutureBuilders.

```
 Future<List<RequirementModel>> _futureRelevant;
 Future<List<RequirementModel>> _futureAll;
```

And also two methods.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _futureRelevant = getRelevant();
    _futureAll = getAll();
  }
```

Build method: looks like this:

```
        child: check
          ? FutureBuilder<List<RequirementModel>>(
              future: _futureRelevant,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  print(snapshot.data.length);
                  return listViewData(snapshot.data,height,width);
                }
              })
          : FutureBuilder<List<RequirementModel>>(
              future: _futureAll,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return listViewData(snapshot.data,height,width);
                }
          })
```